# How to change the textcolor of UIWebnVIew iPhone

Tags: ios, webview

I am using webview to load the html string it loads the data but it does not change the text colour i am also changing colour but it does not get effect.

```
   NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                               "<head> \n"
                               "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                               "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; text-colour:red}\n"
                               "</style> \n"
                               "</head> \n"
                               "<body>%@</body> \n"
                               "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:18],  texts];
```

It shows default colour not the new one given

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in your CSS code so simply replace

```
 "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; text-colour:red}\n"
```

with

```
 "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; color:red}\n"
```

Hope that will work